# Как правильно ответить на вопрос

Tags: общие-вопросы

Я спросил у друга:

> без курсача на экзамен не пускают?

он ответил:

> нет

имея при этом ввиду, что без курсача на экзамен действительно не пускают. Я же считаю, что ответ "нет" в данной ситуации означает, что можно сдать экзамен, не сдав курсача.  Прав ли мой друг?

Comment: @banan-olivka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

### Короткая версия:

- Задавай вопрос без отрицания.
- Отвечай на заданные с отрицанием вопросы осмысленно (не "да" или
  "нет"; используй отрицаемое в вопросе слово, с отрицанием или без).

По сути вопроса:

- Ты задал вопрос в неудобной форме
- Друг дал ответ в неоднозначной форме

Оба были неправы.

### Длинная версия:

Хорошо известная ситуация. На любой вопрос, содержащий отрицание, нельзя дать ответ "да" или "нет", имеющий однозначное толкование (формально толкование обоих ответов одинаковое, но кто в устной речи заботится о формальностях?).

*"На Stackexchange не дают ответы?"*

Положительные:

- *"Дают"*

Отрицательные:

- *"Не дают"*
- *"Да, не дают"*
- *"Нет, не дают"*
- *"Да"* (не дают)
- *"Нет"* (не дают)

Как было верно замечено в комментариях, **удаление отрицания** из вопроса полностью решает проблему:

*"На Stackexchange дают ответы?"*

Положительные:

- *"Да"*
- *"Дают"*
- *"Да, дают"*

Отрицательные:

- *"Нет"*
- *"Не дают"*
- *"Нет, не дают"*

Answer (score 0):

Если это серьезный вопрос, то да.)))

В русском языке (в отличие от английского, например) это просто "нет" модно понимать и как "нет, это не так" (ты неправ), и как "нет, не пускают". Поэтому лучше давать более развернутый ответ, а ваш реальный или возможный спор однозначного разрешения не имеет. Оба одинаковы правы и неправы.

даже не знаю, чем тут еще модно помочь. Опрос разве провести, как кто понимает. Но скорее всего большинство согласится именно с тем, что оба понимания возможны.

Comment: Мне стоило уточнить, что меня интересует не то, как воспринимается ответ "нет", а то, насколько такой ответ правильный. У меня есть пара аргументов. Если, как это любят делать англичане, я добавлю хвостик ", не так ли?", то мне становится очевидно, что ответ "нет" несёт совсем другой смысл, нежели имел ввиду мой друг. Аналогичная ситуация складывается, если я заменю "не пускают" на что-нибудь без не, например так: "без курсача на экзамен можно не приходить?" Разве я не прав?