# Да или нет. И почему!

Tags: образование

> - 3 сентября первокурсники не учатся ведь?
> - Нет, с 4 числа учитесь.

Человек правильно написал *нет* или нужно было написать *да*?

Answer (score 2):

Корректные варианты ответов:

*3 сентября первокурсники не учатся ведь? — **Нет, не учатся...***

*3 сентября первокурсники не учатся ведь? — **Да, не учатся...***

(Слова *да* и *нет* в ответах можно опустить.)

См. ответ [**справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру на вопрос № 281936:**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281936)

> ...В советском мультфильме *"Маша больше не лентяйка"* бабушка
>   спрашивает у внучки: *"Разве ты не хозяйка своих рук"*? Маша отвечает:
>   *"Да, не хозяйка".*
>
> Я бы на месте Маши ответил *"Нет, не хозяйка".* Как правильнее?..
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> В ответах на подобные вопросы недостаточно одних только слов *да* и
>   *нет*. Они здесь малоинформативны. Можно ответить: *«Не хозяйка», «Да, не хозяйка», «Нет, не хозяйка».* Главное – слова *не хозяйка* должны
>   присутствовать в ответе.

Comment: "Нет" - это отрицание. Как можно отрицать правду? Это разговорный вариант замены "не" на "нет".

Comment: @oleedd Таков уж наш язык. Кстати, похожий вопрос уже здесь был: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/45089&ved=2ahUKEwjd1rD_2bLkAhVTa8AKHahsCcYQjjgwAXoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw13uxOaFLl8pD40rT-v0oHb

Comment: Но это отличный способ запутать собеседника.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **да**.

**Не учатся** *ведь? || **Да** (правда), 3 сентября **не учатся**. А учатся с 4 числа.*

("Не учатся" является правдой - поэтому "да".)

Если с отрицанием, тогда так:

*Не учатся ведь? || **Не** учатся. А учатся с 4 числа.*